# JQuery DISABLED Issues

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have read a ton of articles here and done some Googling however I cannot get a handle on what is wrong with my code.

The basic attempt is to set a field to disabled when my SharePoint form loads and later down the page enable it again based on the values of some other dropdowns.

Here is my code ( I truncated it down because there is more to it)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("select[title='Has this been logged in Attorney Issue Log? Required Field')").prop( "disabled", true );
 $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Has this been logged in Attorney Issue Log?')").closest("tr").hide();
 $("select[title='Escalated Issue Type Required Field']").change(function() {
           SOME STUFF ABOUT THE OPTIONS
 )};
 )};
 </script>
```

None of the code after I set .prop("disabled", true) executes. I tried using an older version of JQuery and using .attr instead however the result was the same. I tried ("disabled", "disabled") and got the same thing.

If I place the .HIDE() first that table row does get hidden telling me that the code does execute. I have tried a number of combination and I am at a loss so I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `Required Field')"` should use a bracket: `Required Field']"` -- but better yet, use a unique class or id instead.

Comment: Also as you can see from your problem, the selectors you've chosen are an extremely poor choice.  You've tightly coupled your display text to javascript.  Changing text on an element should not break javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I feel like an idiot. Happens when you spend all day looking at this stuff.